# Join 4 tables into a single table in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have 4 tables which contain multiple values. As of now I am manually combining the values of all the tables into a single table i.e exporting the values of all 4 tables in xlsx format and making another excel document and putting those values and uploading them to a new table. So this is what I'm doing right now to fetch the values.

**$sql = "SELECT * FROM foodDatabase";**

I want something like this

**SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AND TABLE2 AND TABLE3 AND TABLE4;**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: This is really basic. You should take a SQL tutorial

Answer (score 0):

SQL UNION Operator

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TABLE3
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TABLE4
```